# Can you change the architecture in Ghidra after importing?

Tags: decompilation, arm, disassemblers, ghidra

I've been analyzing an ARMv7 binary for a while and have done a lot of work with it (e.g. labeling functions, creating structs, labeling globals etc.). Unfortunately, I just realized that Ghidra mistakenly selected ARMv8 when it was being imported, which is causing some decompilation issues.

Is there a way to change the architecture at this point without needing to reimport? I know you can override the architecture when its being imported, but I have yet to figure out how to change the architecture after the fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can right click the file you import at **Active Project** tab in ghidra main window, and select **Set Language**

[image: screenshot]